# Database design question

Tags: database-design

I have a story with lots of acts. These acts are not consecutive (I don't know which is first act or second, third, and so on).

Every story ends with a challenge.

To represent all in a relational database I have used the following tables:

```
Story
---------------------------------------
Id              | PK
Name            | String
FirstActId      | FK to ACT table

Act
---------------------------------------
Id              | PK
StoryId         | FK to STORY table
Name            | String
Description     | Very long string
NextActionType  | FK to ACTIONTYPE table
NextId          | Its value depends on NextActionType

ActionType
---------------------------------------
Id              | PK
Name            | Values= 'Act', 'Challenge', 'Story'.

Challenge
---------------------------------------
Id              | PK
Name            | String
Description     | Very long string
NextActionType  | FK to ACTIONTYPE table
NextId          | Its value depends on NextActionType
```

I use `Story.FirstActId` to know which is the first act for story (I'm trying to say that `"Select MIN(Id) from Act where StoryId = ?"` doesn't work.).

And then, I use `Act.NextId` to know which act or challenge goes after this act. `Act.NextId` can be an Act PK or a Challenge PK or a Story PK. This depends on `Act.NextActionType` value.

What do you think? Is it a good design?

My problem is I have **Challenge** table without any relationship with any other table.

**UPDATE**
In other words, I need a system to know where to go next. I will have the following situations:

story->act->challenge->act -> new story
story->act->challente-> new story

**NOTE**: act can be more than one.

Comment: If you don't know which act is first, second, etc. how can you store FirstActId?

Comment: I know which act is first when I add stories and acts. I'm trying to say that "Select MIN(Id) from Act where StoryId = ?" doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your table design is not in 3NF and has the potential for update anomalies (for example, if the first act of a story is deleted the entire chain is broken; if its NextActId is updated, the chain changes completely).  Another problem is that you must recursively seek on the chain to get all of the Acts for a story rather than getting them in one query.

If you want to be able to reuse acts between stories, you should use an indirection table:

```
StoriesActsMap
--------------
storyid
actid
ordinal_number
```

If you don't need to reuse acts between stories, then you can just stick with the Acts table:

```
   Act
   -------------
   actid
   actDescription, etc.
   ordinal_number
   storyid
```

The handling of challenges also depends.

Can a challenge also be an act?  If so, you should store it in Acts and have an ActsType table:

```
   Act
   --------------
   actid
   acttypeid
   ...see rest of Act above

   ActsType
   --------------
   acttypeid
   acttype (Act, Challenge)
```

If a challenge is an act, is its definition as a Challenge obviated by its position in the story (last)?  If so, the ActsType is not necessary, it would just be the MAX ordinal number on StoriesActMap/Act

If a Challenge is a Challenge and can never be an Act, it should be stored in separate table.  You can either have a StoriesChallengeMap table if Challenges can be reused between stories, or just the Challenge table with a `storyid` key to map it to Stories if they cannot be reused.  `storyid` would be a unique key on these tables since a Story only has one challenge.

Assuming that a Challenge is always a Challenge and Acts/Challenges cannot be shared between stories, the design would be as follows:

```
Story
----------
storyid
other info

Act
----------
actid
storyid
actorder (ordinal number of acts, (actorder, storyid) is a prime)
other info

Challenge
----------
chid
storyid
other info
```

Now you can get all of the Acts and the Challenge for a story in one query.  Beware that a deletion of a story will orphan Acts/a Challenge if there are no foreign key constraints.

Comment: After reading your update to the question, my design does not handle the Story following an Act.  Does a Story always follow a Challenge?  Or can a Story be the next action at any time?

Comment: I'm using nextActionType and nextId to set up a 'navigation' I can have: story->act->challenge->act->new story. Or this one: story->act->challenge->new story. Acts can be more than one. I'm not sure if've understood your question. If you need more details, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, the `Challenge` is simply a (sub)type of `Act`. Considering that the `Act` table contains all columns needed in `Challenge`, you can simply drop tables `Challenge` and `ActionType`. Use `ThisActionType` column instead of the `NextActionType` which could contain `C,A` if you need to know what type of Act it is (standard vs challenge).

Also get rid of the `FirstActID` from the Story table and find a way to identify first/last act in the `Act` table -- every act can belong to only one story in this model, and first and last are obviously special.

So, by the time it's done it would look something like this

[image]

`ActPosition` (F,L,A) would be used to identify first, last, any.

Comment: I've forget to say that nextActionType can be a story also. I've updated my question with better details. Sorry.

Comment: @VansFannel, In this case the `NextActID` would simply point to the first act of the different `StoryID`.

Answer (score 0):

I would change some things:

```
Act
---------------------------------------
...
NextAct         | FK to Act table, can be NULL
Challenge       | FK to Challenge table, can be NULL

No need of ActionType
```

You will save space. An act is followed by an Act if NextAct is not null,
an Act is followed by a challenge if Challenge is not null.

Of course, the condition (NextAct xor Challenge) must always be true. You can assert this by adding a table constraint on insertions in Act table.

If you have a lot of type of next actions (since we only have two actions here, it is easy), you will need to look at the problem in a different way:
"a challenge has one Act",
"an Act can have one Act"
"ActionN has on act"

Like that, you will be able to find the next action as below:

```
SELECT
  challenge_id,
  act_id,
  ...
FROM
  Act
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  Act NextAct ON Act.next_act_id = NextAct.act_id
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  Challenge ON Act.challenge_id = Challenge_id
```

At least one will not be NULL.

Comment: I've forget to say that nextActionType can be a story also. I've updated my question with better details. Sorry.

Comment: It does not change anything, a tree/graph structure must be created with relations Children -> Parent and not Parent -> Children.

Answer (score 0):

To me, Acts & Challenges seem to store the same kind of information, hence putting them in different tables seems overkill.

I'd probably go for..

```
Story
---------------------------------------
Id              | PK
Name            | String
FirstActId      | FK to ACT table

Items (Acts or Challenges)
---------------------------------------
Id              | PK
StoryId         | FK to STORY table
Name            | String
Description     | Very long string
Order           | Int - which position this Act / Challenge should go in
```

You could have a flag indicating if something is an Act or Challenge.

However, if I understand your description, then you could identify items by having a convention, e.g. setting the first item's `Order` as 0 making it the first Act, and when an Act / Challenge is the last item in the set (ie `Max(Order)`) denoting it as a Challenge.